# M1 Pro MacBook swaps a lot

Tags: macbook-pro, ssd, memory, apple-silicon, virtual-memory

I have a 10 core M1 Pro MacBook Pro with `16` GB RAM and `1` TB storage, on Ventura 13.0. It seems to suffer from excessive SSD writes for no apparent reason, a situation that seems very similar to what multiple users described soon after the M1 chips came out, for example here: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/252532855

Smartctl report:

```
=== START OF SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

SMART/Health Information (NVMe Log 0x02)
Critical Warning:                   0x00
Temperature:                        34 Celsius
Available Spare:                    100%
Available Spare Threshold:          99%
Percentage Used:                    2%
Data Units Read:                    266,856,852 [136 TB]
Data Units Written:                 132,865,271 [68.0 TB]
Host Read Commands:                 3,388,169,733
Host Write Commands:                847,144,045
Controller Busy Time:               0
Power Cycles:                       143
Power On Hours:                     841
Unsafe Shutdowns:                   7
Media and Data Integrity Errors:    0
Error Information Log Entries:      0
```

Various articles mention that the SMART reporting might not be accurate. So I also looked things up in Activity monitor, which seems to match the SMART data pretty well in my case:

[image]
[image]

This is over a `11.5` hour period, so almost `4.5` GB written per hour, and the laptop spent at least 2 hours idle in screen saver mode during this time, with light browsing, youtube and video calls in the others. I have an external monitor connected. From what I read, the `kernel_task` bytes written seems to be what the OS writes to swap. Regardless, that's `19.33` GB that I cannot account for. I have a lot of chrome tabs (30-40) open, but only 4-5 that I often switch between. I also have some messenger apps open and some coding editors. There are no noticeable slowdowns that would indicate low memory and Activity Manager doesn't suggest this might be the case either:

[image]

It's interesting to me that the `Swap Used` field here does not correspond at all to how much `kernel_task` has written. Some sort of error in reporting, or just a lot of things getting deleted from swap and others written, while maintaining the count around the `3.6` GB shown here? It's around this value all the time when I check.

All this is similar to what people were describing previously, before a patch supposedly addressed this sometime back in Big Sur.

While I'm not noticing any slowdowns and everything seems fine, this SSD usage is a lot higher than I've ever seen.

- Is this normal?
- Can I realistically do anything to reduce the amount of data written to swap / by `kernel_task`?

Comment: Memory pressure yellow, so Normal? yes with your workload (VMs, Chrome and developer) and only 16GB. You can turn off all swapping - but I would not recommend that.

Comment: I am no expert on swap, but pretty sure that kernel_task could be *many* things amongst swap. So just because it wrote 19GB I highly doubt that they were all swap.

Comment: @Gilby I consider it normal because there are no performance issues. I've used intel macbooks, windows PCs, linux PCs similarly or even more intensely and the writes were nowhere near this.

Comment: @X_841 do you know what other things it could be so I can maybe look into them?

Comment: @IVlad So what is the issue? The GB of writes by kernel_task is not unusual. My 8 GB MacBook has a far higher proportion of writes by kernel_task than yours does and my memory is green. If you want to reduce swapping, don't run QEMU except when essential - it is consuming over half your RAM. I would say your Mac is memory constrained, but if performing ok then I don't see an issue.

Comment: @Gilby other than excessive SSD wear, nothing. But that's an important one IMO, and I'd like to at least understand why it happens. It's written 5 GB overnight while in sleep mode. Is yours M1 as well?

Comment: What is it you're *actually* worried about? SSD life? My oldest SSD is 8 years old, TBW 250TB, which is about 1/3 its expected life-span.

Comment: @Tetsujin yes, SSD life. Expected life-span depends a lot on SSD type and usage. You've written 250TB in 8 years. At this rate, I will reach it in under 2 years, and "this rate" hasn't seen any intense workflows yet. There's no data that I can find on this model's SSD type and TBW ratings.

Comment: You can expect TBW on a modern 1TB SSD to be in the range of 1200 - that's based on the manufacturer's expectation of warranty period. Like a car manufacturer will guarantee 50,000 miles, doesn't mean the car will die at 51k. If you're running it hard into swap all the time, you're just going to be shortening the life-span… but by how much, who knows. Probably it will live longer than you care to still own it. What's your usual turnaround time between computers? Mine is a decade… never lost a drive on a Mac yet - though once lost 3 Win boot drives in a year [yes, I backup, no data lost]. ;)

Comment: @Tetsujin yeah, I'll agree it's likely going to outlast my usual turnaround time of 4-5 years. 1200 TBW is usually for MLC drives, for TLC ones I haven't seen more than 600, but even that is quite a lot, and like you've said, only the warranty value. I don't know which ones Apple uses.

Comment: No, I don't know for sure. I'd stop worrying about it & put belt & braces on your backup strategy instead. For what you seem to need to do, your RAM is under-spec rather than your SSD; but that's always been an issue with laptops. We have an M1 iMac here which suffers the same RAM/swap issues. The others are big old cheesegrater Pros with 64GB… no issues.